# Getting data from many to many relation with rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing a rails app with mysql database.

Theres bunch of tables but for this task I am using only 3.
Students, Courses and CoursesPerStudent.

I have models for students and courses(no model for the third).
The tables are already populated.

The tables:

students - id,name,family,address,phone,email,status,path
courses - courseCode, courseName, hours
coursesperstudent - code, student(same ids as in students table ids but not a oreign key),path,course(courses table code(foreign key)),examMark.

Now the thing is i need to show for each student a list of the courses realted to him.

How should i do it? 
Should i create model for the third table? how should i call it? and combine the two other tables in one to show specific courses?

Or there some other way?

Hopefully someone will help because im out of answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 - Many to many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307880/rails-4-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

If you make right has_and_belongs_to_many association you can call:

```
Student.find(id).courses
```

it return collection of courses

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association